# utf8_decode error with ampersand (&)

Tags: php, simplexml, utf8-decode

I have been building an API which returns XML code. For example, the API will return:

```
<message>hello, this is a message &amp; it used htmlsepcialchars</message>
```

I am using file_get_contents() and simplexml_load_string() to load the returned information into an array.

I then used utf8_decode() to convert the message into a friendly charset on the receiving website. However, I receive the following message which pin points to the ampersand (&) in the message:

```
Warning: main() [function.main]: unterminated entity reference
```

Due to the ampersand, the rest of the message is truncated. Any ideas how to get around this problem?

Comment: Perhaps `simplexml_load_string()` is rendering the `&amp;` into just an ampersand? Perhaps re-encoding it would help. (`htmlentities()` may help here.)

Comment: Quick comment: you don't need `file_get_contents()`, just use `simplexml_load_file('/path/to/file');` -- Also, please provide a link to the file that produces that error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my answer, user error. I was basically escaping again somewhere in my code.

Answer (score 0):

it seems your ampersand is not encoded so either double decode it or put it in CDATA field.

Usually special characters like that should be put in CDATA fields. it saves the trouble of having to encode.
php DOM creation functions have what you need.

```
$doc->createCDATASection
```

and of course :

http://www.w3schools.com/Xml/xml_cdata.asp

and
http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.domdocument-create-cdata-section.php

Comment: There is virtually no scenario where it's in your interest *not* to "encode" (or escape, rather) special characters. You don't want to blindly put whatever text between `<![CDATA[` and `]]>` and hope that the text doesn't contain something that will make your XML invalid. If you use DOM methods, the input is automatically escaped, including for CDATA, so no problem there.

Comment: that is why i said it saved him the trouble of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, simpleXML strings must be utf8 encoded, and values entities should be escaped.
Is `utf_decode()` really necessary in your code ?

Comment: SimpleXML is not limited to UTF-8, it can load most encodings as long as the file is valid (IOW as long as the correct encoding is declared.)